# Use String for Pattern but Exclude it from Being Removed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

i'm pretty new on regex, i have learned something by the way, but is still pour knowledge!

so i want ask you for clarification on how it work!

assuming i have the following strings, as you can see they can be formatted little different way one from another but they are very similar!

```
DTSTART;TZID="America/Chicago":20030819T000000
DTEND;TZID="America/Chicago":20030819T010000
DTSTART;TZID=US/Pacific
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE
```

now i want replace everything **between** the **first A-Z block** and the **colon** so for example i would keep

```
DTSTART:20030819T000000
DTEND:20030819T010000
DTSTART
DTSTART
```

so on my very noobs knowledge i have worked out this shitty regex! :-(

```
preg_replace( '/^[A-Z](?!;[A-Z]=[\w\W]+):$/m' , '' , $data );
```

but why i'm sure this regex will not work!? :-)

Pls help me!

PS: the title of question is pretty explaned, i want also know how for example use a well know string block for match another...

```
preg_replace( '/^[DTSTART](?!;[A-Z]=[\w\W]+):$/m' , '' , $data );
```

..without delete `DTSTART`

Thanks for the time!

Regards
Luca Filosofi

Comment: Thanks to every one, just great answers here; so i have upvoted (+1) each of you! i want check the **salathe** one cause i really like his elegant `^DT(?:START|END)` regex! thanks to all again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a relatively simple regex like the following.

```
$subject = 'DTSTART;TZID="America/Chicago":20030819T000000
DTEND;TZID="America/Chicago":20030819T010000
DTSTART;TZID=US/Pacific
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE';

echo preg_replace('/^[A-Z]+\K[^:\n]*/m', '', $subject) . PHP_EOL;
```

It looks for a series of capital letters at the start of a line, resets the match starting point (that's what `\K` does) to the end of those and matches anything not a colon or newline (i.e. the parts you want to remove). Those matched parts are then replaced with an empty string.

The output from the above would be

```
DTSTART:20030819T000000
DTEND:20030819T010000
DTSTART
DTSTART
```

If the lines that you are interested in will only ever start with `DTSTART` or `DTEND` then we could be more precise about what to match (e.g. `^DT(?:START|END)`) but `[A-Z]` obviously covers both of those.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove everything between a semicolon and either a colon or the end of the line, right? So use that as your expression. You're overcomplicating things.

```
preg_replace('/(?:;.+?:)|(?:;.+?$)/m','',$data);
```

It's a pretty simple expression. Either match `(?:;.+?:)` or `(?:;.+?$)`, which differ only by their terminator (the first one matches up to a colon, the second one matches up to the end of the line).

Each is a non-capturing group that starts with a semicolon, reluctantly reads in all characters, then stops at the terminator. Everything matched by this is removable according to your description.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain part of the matched pattern in a substitution, you put parentheses around it and then refer to it by $1 (or whichever grouping it is).

For example:

```
s/^(this is a sentence) to edit/$1/
```

gives "this is a sentence"

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this example work similarly as your problem

\w+): (?P\d+)/', $str, $matches);

    /* This also works in PHP 5.2.2 (PCRE 7.0) and later, however 
     * the above form is recommended for backwards compatibility */
    // preg_match('/(?\w+): (?\d+)/', $str, $matches);

    print_r($matches);

    ?>

```
The above example will output:

Array
(
    [0] => foobar: 2008
    [name] => foobar
    [1] => foobar
    [digit] => 2008
    [2] => 2008
)
```

so if u need only digit u need to print $matches[digit]